# NgRx - Get error validation from backend and pass to component

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Im trying to grab the errors messages from api and show inside my form inputs so the user can see whats is wrong with the data that is being submitted.

Response From API:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "This name is already in use."
    ]
  }
}
```

user-form.component.ts

```
this.store.dispatch(new actions.CreateUser(user));
```

user.effect.ts

```
@Effect()
  CreateUser$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.CREATE_USER),
    map((action: UserActions.CreateUser) => action.payload),
    switchMap(payload => {
      return this.userService.save(payload).pipe(
        map((user: User) => {
          return new UserActions.CreateUserSuccess(user);
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          return of(new UserActions.CreateUserFail());
        })
      );
    })
  );
```

How can I grab that error and pass it back to my component?

Should I do like inside the effects and subscribe it to the Actions waiting for an CreateUserFail error? Im not sure if its a good practice since it will listen to all kind of Actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We built a selector and subscribed to that selector.

**Effect**

```
  @Effect()
  createProduct$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(productActions.ProductActionTypes.CreateProduct),
    map((action: productActions.CreateProduct) => action.payload),
    mergeMap((product: Product) =>
      this.productService.createProduct(product).pipe(
        map(newProduct => (new productActions.CreateProductSuccess(newProduct))),
        catchError(err => of(new productActions.CreateProductFail(err)))
      )
    )
  );
```

**Reducer**

```
case ProductActionTypes.CreateProductFail:
  return {
    ...state,
    error: action.payload
  };
```

**Selector**

```
export const getError = createSelector(
  getProductFeatureState,
  state => state.error
);
```

**Component**

```
// Watch for changes to the error message
this.errorMessage$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getError));
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
  Error: {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
```

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo4

Comment: Thanks Deborah! And how do you clean that messages so the user dont see them again? A saw that you clean then on success action but maybe the user just navigate away then backed to the form page.

Comment: You could add an action to clear the messages and clear them in the ngOnInit of the component. Or clear them as part of the component destruction.

Comment: Great! You're awesome Deborah. Thank you!

Comment: @DeborahK No one talked about clearing the error/success message from the component until you did. Simple and elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. Gave me direction to implement error handling and spinner/loader functionality as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to change the catchError as follow:

```
catchError(err => {
  return new UserActions.CreateUserFail(err);
})
```

also consider to use implicit return:

```
map( (user: User) => new UserActions.CreateUserSuccess(user) ),
catchError( err => new UserActions.CreateUserFail(err) )
```

Comment: Im not sure how to use your answer. Could you demonstrate a bit more of how to get that message?